# How to clear the form controls after submit the data?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In google chrome when coming back to saved page its empty but in mozilla when return back to same form then showing saved data in controls as it is. So how to clear the form controls after submit the data?

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

but its not working. And also put below code in saving form.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "You work will be lost."; };
```

its clearing the fields when return back to saving page but when we clicking the save button then throwing alert.

so how to save without ask 'Leave this page' option and work clearing the fields after save the page?

Comment: User jquery `$(#this).Clear()`

Comment: where to write this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this

Instead of `return View()`

use `return RedirectToAction("Index")`

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
           return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
          //Your Code//
      //model.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");       
}
```

Comment: I know it.. so thats what I want to explain to u..If I went to another view then how can clear previous view's fields?

Comment: try adding this

[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
           return View();
}